# How to paste href tag as link into a Google document

Tags: google-docs

I have a Google document.  When I copy and paste something from my browser to the document, the text with hyperlinks get translated into hyperlinks in the document.

If I am in emacs or vim and copy html code into the document, Google treats it like text. This is a reasonable assumption. However I'm wondering if there's a way to trick Google into thinking that a href tag should be turned into a hyperlink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no tricks, just built-in tools and scripts.

#### Manual conversion

To turn  http://example.com into http://example.com, select it  and press Ctrl-K (or right-click and choose Link).

This will be a hassle if you pasted in several dozens of these. Then a script is preferable.

#### Conversion with a script

I wrote two functions, for two different conversions:

- <a href="http://example.com">link text</a> to <a href="http://example.com">link text</a>
- <a href="http://example.com">link text</a> to [link text](http://www.example.com)

Both are added to the document menu by the onOpen function.

The approach is the same in both cases, the details vary in step 3.

1. Use  [Body.findText](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#findText(String)) method to find the elements containing the text of interest. (This search method has some support of regular expressions, although not much.)
2. Obtain the text string from each matching element: `.getElement().asText().getText()`
3. Use the JavaScript regex engine to search (and substitute if necessary).
4. Finally, linkify by using [Text.setLinkUrl](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#setLinkUrl(Integer,Integer,String)) method.

```
function linkify() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var range = body.findText("<a[^<]*</a>");
  while (range) {  
    var nextRange = body.findText("<a[^<]*</a>", range);
    var elem = range.getElement().asText();
    var str = elem.getText();
    var re = /href=(\W)(.*?)\1/g;
    var result = re.exec(str); 
    while (result) {
      var index = result.index; 
      var url = result[2]; 
      elem.setLinkUrl(index+6, index+url.length+5, url);
      result = re.exec(str);
    }
    range = nextRange;
  }
}

function replaceWithLink() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var range = body.findText("<a[^<]*</a>");
  while (range) {  
    var nextRange = body.findText("<a[^<]*</a>", range);
    var elem = range.getElement().asText();
    var str = elem.getText();
    var result = /<a[^<]*<\/a>/.exec(str); 
    while (result) {
      var link = result[0];
      var index = result.index;
      var url = /href=(\W)(.*)\1/.exec(link)[2];
      var text = />(.*)</.exec(link)[1];
      elem.replaceText(link, text);
      elem.setLinkUrl(index, index+text.length-1, url);
      str = str.replace(link, text);
      result = /<a[^<]*<\/a>/.exec(str);
    }
    range = nextRange;
  }
}

function onOpen() {
  DocumentApp.getUi()
             .createMenu('Custom')
             .addItem('Recognize href as a link', 'linkify')
             .addItem('Replace <a> elements with links', 'replaceWithLink')
             .addToUi();
}
```

Comment: I'm confused.  How do I get Google Docs to run this javascript code?  It just treats it like text when I paste it in.

Comment: In the menu, see Tools > Script Editor

Comment: Ah-ha!  Thanks!  That does look like it will work.